# Can I encode my serialized form data with jquery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, serialization, mysql-real-escape-string

I've run into an interesting problem. If I submit my PHP form the "tradtional" way with an action via post I capture the form data as follows:

```
headline:I%27m+just+here+for+friends%21
```

I escape the data server side before adding it to my DB using : mysql_real_escape_string($string) and everything is great.

If I now submit that same form using jqueries $.post method and pass it my serialize data

```
$.post("save_data.php", $("#form_id").serialize(),
    function(data) {
        // process my results
    }
);
```

it looks like this:

```
headline:I'm+just+here+for+friends!
```

The mysql_real_escape call doesn't actually work anymore because I'm assuming the data has or has not been encoded properly.  Is there a work around for this or a way to encode the form data before posting it?

Here is how I'm currently processing the form data inside PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $result = updateDataEntry($_POST);
}
```

$_POST sees the serialized form data as: **headline:I'm+just+here+for+friends!** so using mysql_real_escape_string($string) inside my updateDataEntry method is still adding escape characters inside the DB.

Comment: What's wrong with calling `mysql_real_escape_string` with data posted via jQuery? No reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: It works but it sends the form data in a slightly different format (see above)  The difference is causing the DB to escape the special characters

Comment: Which characters are being escaped that shouldn't be. Can you give an example of what gets insert in the DB in each case?

Comment: the single quote is being escaped in the DB like so: I\'m just here for friends!

Comment: the strange part is I only see this when using $.post and passing it my form data as a serialized string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of tearing my hair out I found the issue.  magic quotes were enabled in my php.ini file.  If anyone else runs into this you can turn them off as shown below:

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Now everything is working great!

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix is to always submit it to the form in the same format. Run PHP's `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` on it before passing it to $.post for the second time.

Comment: I'm a little confused...you're saying I should post the data to a another php file the first time and return the data from htmlentities before posting it a second time?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string` prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a, right? So it does not affect the `%` and special chars. If you want to insert the string exactly like `headline:I%27m+just+here+for+friends%21` into db just encode it with [urlencode](http://cl.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) before escaping.